# Stacking triangles while doubling in size using python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm trying to create a total of 4 triangles that centrally stack on top of the other while doubling in size. I seem to have gotten most of it right but for some reason the last 2 triangles start to steer slightly left, where am I going wrong? Below is the code I've written so far.

```
from turtle import *

number_of_shapes = 4

for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
    for sides in range(1, 4):
        forward(shape * 20)
        left(120)

    penup()
    left(120)
    forward(shape * 20)
    right(120)
    pendown()
```

This is what I expect to get:

[image: Expected image]

This is what I get from my code:

[image: Result image]

Comment: You have to move farther right as the triangles get bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the size of the side of your triangles. In the first iteration of `for shape in range(...)`, you have a side that is `1 * 20 = 20` long. In the second, you have `2 * 20 = 40`. In the third, you have `60`. In the fourth, you have `80`. This isn't increasing by a factor of `2` every time. The way you have coded it, you need the size to increase to twice its last value to get a symmetric figure:

```
from turtle import *

number_of_shapes = 4
side = 20

for shape in range(number_of_shapes):
    for sides in range(3):
        forward(side)
        left(120)
    penup()
    left(120)
    forward(side)
    right(120)
    pendown()
    side = side * 2 # Next side is 2x previous value
```

[image]

If you *don't* want to have the factor of `2`, you need to make sure you start your new triangle at the correct spot.

```
for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
    for sides in range(1, 4):
        forward(shape * 20)
        left(120)

    penup()
    left(120)
    forward(shape * 20)
    right(120)

    # At this point, the turtle is at a distance of `shape*20` to the left of the top vertex
    # You want it to be at a distance of (shape+1) * 20 / 2 so that your figure is symmetric
    # So move it forward by that amount before you `pendown()`
    dist = shape*20 - (shape+1) * 10
    forward(dist)

    pendown()
```

[image]